# Get a dynamic timestamp in php?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How would you calculate an unix timestamp of the `January 1st` of the **current year** in PHP?

What I mean by **current year** is that I don't want to put `2012` in it because it should be a dynamic date, next year it should be `2013` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
echo strtotime('01 january ' . date('Y'));
```

Comment: The `date('Y')` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have a date and time like this `2012-01-01 06:30:54` and you want to convert them to unix timestamp?

If that's the case then `strtotime()` is the best way to go buddy.

e.g : `strtotime("2012-01-01 06:30:54");`

or

```
$datetime = "2012-01-01 06:30:54";

echo strtotime($datetime);
```

Comment: if you want the the date to be dynamic then just put it into this format 

date("Y-m-d h:i:s");